# Shortest way to remove characters in a variable

Tags: bash, string, variable

There are many ways to remove characters in a variable.

The shortest way I found out so far is [`tr`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html):

```
OUTPUT=a\'b\"c\`d_123and_a_lot_more
OUTPUT=$(echo "$OUTPUT"|tr -d "'\`\"")
echo $OUTPUT
```

Is there a faster way?

And is this quoting-safe for quotes like `'`, `"` and `` ` `` itself?

Comment: I think you can keep using `tr`. BASH's PE is good but tr is much faster in this case. e.g. `echo "$OUTPUT" | tr -dc '[[:alpha:]]'`  since you want to have alphanumerics only

Comment: Since you're interested in being quoting-savvy: Always quote your variables! `echo "$OUTPUT"`. Or better: `printf "%s\n" "$OUTPUT"`. (What happens when `OUTPUT="-n"`?)

Comment: You might also consider browsing [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), especially the [bash](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash/25573#25573) tips.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's see. The shortest I can come up with is a tweak of your `tr` solution:

```
OUTPUT="$(tr -d "\"\`'" <<<$OUTPUT)"
```

Other alternatives include the already mentioned variable substitution which can be shorter than shown so far:

```
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//[\'\"\`]}"
```

And `sed` of course though this is longer in terms of characters:

```
OUTPUT="$(sed s/[\'\"\`]//g <<<$OUTPUT)"
```

I'm not sure if you mean shortest in length or in terms of time taken. In terms of length these two are as short as it gets (or as I can get it anyway) when it comes to removing those specific characters. So, which is fastest? I tested by setting the `OUTPUT` variable to what you had in your example but repeated several dozen times:

```
$ echo ${#OUTPUT} 
4900

$ time tr -d "\"\`'" <<<$OUTPUT
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time sed s/[\'\"\`]//g <<<$OUTPUT
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time echo ${OUTPUT//[\'\"\`]}
real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.000s
```

As you can see, the `tr` is clearly the fastest, followed closely by `sed`.  Also, it seems like using `echo` is actually slightly faster than using `<<<`:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do 
    ( time echo $OUTPUT | tr -d "\"\`'" > /dev/null ) 2>&1
done | grep -oP 'real.*m\K[\d.]+' | awk '{k+=$1;} END{print k/NR}'; 
0.0025
$ for i in {1..10}; do 
    ( time tr -d "\"\`'" <<<$OUTPUT > /dev/null ) 2>&1 
  done | grep -oP 'real.*m\K[\d.]+' | awk '{k+=$1;} END{print k/NR}'; 
0.0029
```

Since the difference is tiny, I ran the above tests 10 times for each of the two
and it turns out that the fastest is indeed the one you had to begin with:

```
echo $OUTPUT | tr -d "\"\`'"
```

However, this changes when you take into account the overhead of assigning to a variable, here, using `tr` is slightly slower than the simple replacement:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do
    ( time OUTPUT=${OUTPUT//[\'\"\`]} ) 2>&1
  done | grep -oP 'real.*m\K[\d.]+' | awk '{k+=$1;} END{print k/NR}'; 
0.0032

$ for i in {1..10}; do
    ( time OUTPUT=$(echo $OUTPUT | tr -d "\"\`'")) 2>&1
  done | grep -oP 'real.*m\K[\d.]+' | awk '{k+=$1;} END{print k/NR}'; 
0.0044
```

So, in conclusion, when you simply want to view the results, use `tr` but if you want to reassign to a variable, using the shell's string manipulation features is faster since they avoid the overhead of running a separate subshell.

Comment: Since the OP is interested in setting the modified value back into `OUTPUT`, you will have to account for command substitution sub-shell overhead involved in `tr` and `sed` solutions

Comment: @1_CR yes but since that will be the case whichever method he uses, I figured it is irrelevant.

Comment: Not quite, `OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//[\`\"\']/}"`  does not involve command substitution

Comment: @1_CR ah, I see, yes, you're quite right and that does change the result. Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: The methods that involve a command substitution have the downside of somewhat mangling the string. (You can avoid it but at the expense of making the command significantly more complex.) In particular, command substitution removes trailing newlines.

Answer (score 26):

You could use [variable substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ OUTPUT=a\'b\"c\`d
$ echo "$OUTPUT"
a'b"c`d
```

Use that syntax: `${parameter//pattern/string}` to replace all occurrences of the pattern with the string.

```
$ echo "${OUTPUT//\'/x}"
axb"c`d
$ echo "${OUTPUT//\"/x}"
a'bxc`d
$ echo "${OUTPUT//\`/x}"
a'b"cxd
$ echo "${OUTPUT//[\'\"\`]/x}"
axbxcxd
```

Comment: @rubo77 `echo ${OUTPUT//[\`\"\']/x}` gives `axbxcxa`

Comment: It's incorrect to name the expansion "variable expansion". It is called "parameter expansion".

Comment: @gena2x - I don't understand what your comment means here?

Answer (score 13):

In bash or zsh it is:

```
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//[\`\"\']/}"
```

Note that `${VAR//PATTERN/}` removes all instances of the pattern. For more information [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

This solution should be fastest for short strings because it doesn't involve running any external programs. However for very long strings the opposite is true -- it is better to use dedicated tool for text operations, for example:

```
$ OUTPUT="$(cat /usr/src/linux/.config)"

$ time (echo $OUTPUT | OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//set/abc}")
real    0m1.766s
user    0m1.681s
sys     0m0.002s

$ time (echo $OUTPUT | sed s/set/abc/g >/dev/null)
real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.078s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Comment: In fact, `tr` is faster. Regexes and globs are expensive, and while there is no external program here, bash will always be slower than something like `tr`.

Comment: That highly depends on input data and on the regexp implementation.
In your answer you took some specific large data set - but data set may be small. Or different. Also, you measure not time of regexp but time of echo, so i can't be sure if your comparison really fair.

Comment: Good points. However, you can't make claims about speed without testing. In fact, when assigning to a variable this seems faster but when printing to screen `tr` wins (see my answer). I agree that it will depend on many factors but that's exactly why you can't tell which one wins without actually testing it.

Answer (score 7):

If, on the off-chance, you're just trying to handle quotes for reuse ion the shell, then you can do this *without* removing them, and it's dead simple, too:

```
aq() { sh -c 'for a do
       alias "$((i=$i+1))=$a"
       done; alias' -- "$@"
}
```

That function shell quotes any arg array you hand it and increments its output per iterable argument.

Here it is with a few args:

````
aq \
"here's an
ugly one" \
"this one is \$PATHpretty bad, too" \
'this one```****```; totally sucks'
````

#### OUTPUT

````
1='here'"'"'s an
ugly one'
2='this one is $PATHpretty bad, too'
3='this one```****```; totally sucks'
````

That output is from `dash` which typically safe-quotes single-quoted output like `'"'"'`. `bash` would do `'\''`.

Replacing a selection of single, non-whitespace, non-null bytes with another single byte can likely be done quickest in any POSIX shell with `$IFS` and `$*`.

```
set -f; IFS=\"\'\`; set -- $var; printf %s "$*"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
"some ""crazy """"""""string ""here
```

There I just `printf` it so you can see it, but of course, if I had done:

```
var="$*"
```

...rather than the `printf` command `$var`'s value would be what you see in the output there.

When I `set -f` I instruct the shell *not* to glob - in case the string contains characters that could be construed as glob patterns. I do this because the shells parser expands glob patterns *after* it performs field splitting on variables. globbing can be re-enabled like `set +f`. In general - in scripts - I find it useful to set my bang like:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh -f
```

And then to *explicitly enable globbing* with `set +f` on whatever line I might want it.

Field splitting occurs based on the characters in `$IFS`.

There are two kinds of `$IFS` values - `$IFS` whitespace and `$IFS` non-whitespace. `$IFS` whitespace *(space, tab, newline)* delimited fields are specified to elide by *sequence* to a single field *(or none at all if they do not precede something else)* - so...

```
IFS=\ ; var='      '; printf '<%s>' $var
<>
```

But all others are specified to evaluate to a single field *per occurrence* - they are not truncated.

```
IFS=/; var='/////'; printf '<%s>' $var
<><><><><>
```

*All* variable expansions are, by default, `$IFS` delimited data arrays - they split out to separate fields according to `$IFS`. When you `"`-quote one you override that array property and evaluate it as a single string.

So when I do...

```
IFS=\"\'\`; set -- $var
```

I am setting the shell's argument array to the many `$IFS` delimited fields generated by `$var`'s expansion. When it is expanded its constituent values for the characters contained in `$IFS` are *lost* - they are only field separators now - they are `\0NUL`.

`"$*"` - like other double-quoted variable-expansions - also overrides the field-splitting qualities of `$IFS`. But, *in addition*, it substitutes the first byte in `$IFS` *for each delimited field* in `"$@"`. So because `"` was the *first* value in `$IFS` *all subsequent delimiters become `"` in `"$*"`.* And the `"` needn't be in `$IFS` when you split it, either. You could alter `$IFS` *after* `set -- $args` to another value entirely and its *new* first byte would then show up for the field delimiters in `"$*"`. What's more, you can remove all traces of them entirely like:

```
set -- $var; IFS=; printf %s "$*"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
some crazy string here
```

Comment: Very nice, +1. I wonder if it is indeed faster. Could you add some timing tests comparing it to the approaches in my answer? I expect yours will be faster but would like to see.

Comment: @terdon - that depends on the shell. It is *almost definitely* faster than `tr` in any shell, but the difference is iffy in `bash` for the `${var//$c/$newc/}` case. I expect even in that case it will be faster by some margin, but I don't usually worry about that because for this stuff I always use `dash` - which is faster by orders of magnitude in generally every respect. And so it is hard to compare.

Comment: @terdon - I tried. But - even in `bash` - doing `time (IFS=\"\'\`; set -- $var; printf %s "$*")` and `time (var=${var//\'\`/\"/})` both result in `0.0000s` results for all fields. Am I doing something wrong, do you think? There's supposed to be a backslash before the backquote up there but I dunno how to put a backquote in a comment code field.